# Returning a 2d array in C++

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

I have the following function in pseudocode

```
int [][] multiply(int[][] A, int[][] B)
```

What would be the c++ equivalent for this I have the following

```
int [][] multiply(int A[][], int B[][])
```

But it doesn't work, gives compiler errors.

Comment: Don't use c-style arrays in c++ code. Use `std::array` or `std::vector` instead. Also refrain from posting _pseudo-code_. Post a [MCVE] with the verbatim error messages text.

Comment: Unbounded arrays are a ty..., a category of incomplete types. Therefore, the unbounded dimension can only be the outer one.
Also, this is all straight C. Use good C++ abstractions.

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-a-2d-array-to-a-c-function

Comment: You must specify the first dimension. int A[SIZE][], int B[SIZE][]

Comment: Are they fixed size arrays or do they change at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vector<vector<int>> multiply(const vector<vector<int>> &A, const vector<vector<int>> &B)`

Comment: Nested `std::vector` structures have some drawbacks. Their cache hit behavior isn't really optimal. In most cases it's better to wrap just a simple `std::vector<int>` containing a contiguous memory space into a little helper class, and calculate the row and column offsets internally. Also just posting a piece of code without any further explanation as an answer is unlikely to be useful.

Comment: @TheDude does not abide.

Comment: @Justin What do you mean exactly? Anything wrong with what I said?

Comment: [Cultural joke.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Big_Lebowski) He means you don't like the answer.

Comment: No. I know a gentleman who's called himself The Dude far longer than the movie's been around. I had to explain the Abides thing to him a few years ago. Interesting side-note, Popping The Big Lebowski into google to get the wiki link also popped up a show time. Apparently the film is being screened a a local cinema this coming weekend. I think I'll go.